# Excluding Proof Key Validation in WOPI Validator Despite Non-Implementation: How to Configure?

Tags: ms-wopi

I noticed that in the documentation it mentions 'ProofKeys (applicable only for hosts implementing proof key validation),' but I haven't implemented proof keys in my application. Despite this, the WOPI validator still validates them.

How can I configure or omit this validation since it's not applicable to my implementation?

Comment: Why do you think it's not applicable to your implementation?

Comment: I'm facing issue while implementing this in nest js

Comment: Great and why do you think the proofkeys are not applicable in your case?

Comment: Actually, I implemented it but the test cases were failing, now yesterday I got to know there is some issue going on proof key validator.
Here is the link : https://github.com/microsoft/wopi-validator-core/pull/86